# How to change position of login or register succesfull message?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to receive the successful or not successful message after login/register, above my form. 
I'm using Boostrap 3 with some PHP functions. The message is above my navbar and disappears after 3 seconds. That bothers me...
Thanks!

Html file:

```
 <form class="well form-horizontal" action="login.php" method="post"  id="login_form" style="margin-top:50px;" name="login">
  <legend><center><h2><b>Login</b></h2></center></legend><br>
---> here I want to receive the message
<div class="form-group">
....
</form>
```

register.php

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($check_user) !== 0){
    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp; Registered  !</h4>
    </div>';
}
```

script.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () { $("#flash-msg").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");});
```

Comment: You'd need to post all of your HTML but it looks like the `id="flash-msg"` tag just needs to be moved and pasted below the header of your site.

Comment: no if i post in html this message , it will show automatically , without validation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my comment to your question some more.  Move the `<div id="flash-msg"></div>` (or whatever the tag may be) tag from the header to your content area.  Another option would be to use a different html element to show your response.

For example:

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="login.php" method="post"  id="login_form" style="margin-top:50px;" name="login">
  <legend><center><h2><b>Login</b></h2></center></legend><br>
<div id="login-flash-msg" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="form-group">
....
</form>
```

And then change the script.js to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   $("#login-flash-msg").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");});
```

Comment: I tried your option but it doesnt change anything. Maybe there is a code in <?php to show the message there? ?>